# Wordpress rewrite (remove) part of url

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I searched around for an answer. There's a couple that look like this, but most point to a plugin, or feature examples that I can't get working in my case...

So the question:
I created a custom post type for the homepage of my site. I made it the default front page, so now when I enter: **localhost/vhh** I automatically get forwarded to this page: **localhost/vhh/homepage/homepage**

The first "homepage" refers to the custom post type. The second is the name of the "post".
Now I want to remove both, or at a minimum 1 "homepage", so I get:

**localhost/vhh** or **localhost/vhh/homepage**

Can this be done with a WP rewrite rule? And how?